# flexbox justify-content center issue

Tags: css, flexbox

Me and flexbox are trying to get better acquainted, but at the moment we dont see eye to eye. The reason for this is that i'm trying to flex three items on one row, and two on a second row. But for some reason the items on the second row gets centered, instead of starting at the left side of the main axis, working their way to the right side. Which gives the site a weird look because the items arent aligning.

My test site where all code is available [www.mnrb.dk/mdg](http://www.mnrb.dk/mdg)

What my goal is (picture)

[image]

What my code looks like (small block)

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-display: flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  flex-flow: row;

  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  /*Works in conjunction with flex-wrap to remove unwanted vertical "air" between the items on the cross axis*/
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;

  /*Move items on the main (horizontal) axis
  justify content is by default set to flex-start*/
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;

  /*Move items on the cross (vertical) axis
  By default align items is set to stretch, which stretch the item 100% either horrizontal or vertical
  depending on the flex being a row or column.*/
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-wrapper > div {
  max-width: 400px;

  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;

  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">

  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis et lectus eget faucibus. Nunc lobortis scelerisque leo vel tincidunt. Cras magna ante, commodo ac sem pellentesque, tempus egestas mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent egestas placerat ipsum at molestie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac erat dignissim, imperdiet urna vel, rutrum tortor. Mauris facilisis ex eget massa molestie, sed ultricies urna efficitur. </p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Suspendisse aliquet ligula nisi, eget viverra libero porttitor vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam massa sem, placerat in fermentum et, auctor varius diam. Phasellus sed sollicitudin sem, eget porta urna. Phasellus lacus diam, imperdiet non dapibus porttitor, gravida vitae odio. Pellentesque sit amet risus at risus molestie rutrum sed sit amet mauris. Donec at tortor vulputate, tempus dolor id, rutrum nulla. Vivamus cursus orci vel purus ornare blandit. </p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 3</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Suspendisse aliquet ligula nisi, eget viverra libero porttitor vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam massa sem, placerat in fermentum et, auctor varius diam. Phasellus sed sollicitudin sem, eget porta urna. Phasellus lacus diam, imperdiet non dapibus porttitor, gravida vitae odio. Pellentesque sit amet risus at risus molestie rutrum sed sit amet mauris. Donec at tortor vulputate, tempus dolor id, rutrum nulla. Vivamus cursus orci vel purus ornare blandit. </p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <!--TEST-->
  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 4</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Suspendisse aliquet ligula nisi, eget viverra libero porttitor vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam massa sem, placerat in fermentum et, auctor varius diam. Phasellus sed sollicitudin sem, eget porta urna. Phasellus lacus diam, imperdiet non dapibus porttitor, gravida vitae odio. Pellentesque sit amet risus at risus molestie rutrum sed sit amet mauris. Donec at tortor vulputate, tempus dolor id, rutrum nulla. Vivamus cursus orci vel purus ornare blandit. </p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 4</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Suspendisse aliquet ligula nisi, eget viverra libero porttitor vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam massa sem, placerat in fermentum et, auctor varius diam. Phasellus sed sollicitudin sem, eget porta urna. Phasellus lacus diam, imperdiet non dapibus porttitor, gravida vitae odio. Pellentesque sit amet risus at risus molestie rutrum sed sit amet mauris. Donec at tortor vulputate, tempus dolor id, rutrum nulla. Vivamus cursus orci vel purus ornare blandit. </p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong / send me in the right direction.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 34.0.5, Chrome 39.0.2171.71

Comment: The snippet works like you want for me. In your page, the problem is caused by `main div { margin: 0 auto; }`.

Comment: I tried to work with the margin setting, but didnt solve anything over here. I also tried google chrome incognito state. Same issue persists. What browser did you use @Oriol and version?

Comment: I use Firefox 37. Removing `margin: 0 auto` makes the boxes aligned to the left.

Comment: Indeed, "margin: 0px auto" in the "main div" rule is what's causing you trouble. That tells the flexbox to distribute extra space on flex lines to the spaces between/around flex items. Note that the first line is being "centered" just like the second -- there's just less free space on the first line to use for centering.

Comment: Thanks @Oriol when i looked at the correct margin: 0 auto rule everything worked out :) Next issue on the list is being able to stretch an item on both axis, so items with less content than others have the same height. If anyone have some good links i would be greatfull if you toss them to me, i am also relentlessly searching the web to get wiser.

Comment: Chris Coyiers' A Guide to Flexbox is always my go-to compendium for flexbox http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.. Please, answer your own question with the solution to your problem, and accept it - So we can have it closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the:

`justify-content: flex-start;`
to
   `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-display: flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  flex-flow: row;

  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  /*Works in conjunction with flex-wrap to remove unwanted vertical "air" between the items on the cross axis*/
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;


  /*Move items on the main (horizontal) axis
  justify content is by default set to flex-start*/
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;

  /*Move items on the cross (vertical) axis
  By default align items is set to stretch, which stretch the item 100% either horrizontal or vertical
  depending on the flex being a row or column.*/
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-wrapper > div {
  max-width: 400px;

  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;

  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">

  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis et lectus eget faucibus. Nunc lobortis scelerisque leo vel tincidunt. Cras magna ante, commodo ac sem pellentesque, tempus egestas mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante
        ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent egestas placerat ipsum at molestie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac erat dignissim, imperdiet urna vel, rutrum tortor. Mauris facilisis ex eget massa molestie, sed ultricies urna
        efficitur.</p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Suspendisse aliquet ligula nisi, eget viverra libero porttitor vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam massa sem, placerat in fermentum et, auctor varius diam. Phasellus sed
        sollicitudin sem, eget porta urna. Phasellus lacus diam, imperdiet non dapibus porttitor, gravida vitae odio. Pellentesque sit amet risus at risus molestie rutrum sed sit amet mauris. Donec at tortor vulputate, tempus dolor id, rutrum nulla. Vivamus
        cursus orci vel purus ornare blandit.</p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 3</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Suspendisse aliquet ligula nisi, eget viverra libero porttitor vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam massa sem, placerat in fermentum et, auctor varius diam. Phasellus sed
        sollicitudin sem, eget porta urna. Phasellus lacus diam, imperdiet non dapibus porttitor, gravida vitae odio. Pellentesque sit amet risus at risus molestie rutrum sed sit amet mauris. Donec at tortor vulputate, tempus dolor id, rutrum nulla. Vivamus
        cursus orci vel purus ornare blandit.</p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <!--TEST-->
  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 4</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Suspendisse aliquet ligula nisi, eget viverra libero porttitor vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam massa sem, placerat in fermentum et, auctor varius diam. Phasellus sed
        sollicitudin sem, eget porta urna. Phasellus lacus diam, imperdiet non dapibus porttitor, gravida vitae odio. Pellentesque sit amet risus at risus molestie rutrum sed sit amet mauris. Donec at tortor vulputate, tempus dolor id, rutrum nulla. Vivamus
        cursus orci vel purus ornare blandit.</p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <time datetime="2014-12-07"></time>
        <h2>Title 4</h2>
      </header>
      <p>Suspendisse aliquet ligula nisi, eget viverra libero porttitor vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam massa sem, placerat in fermentum et, auctor varius diam. Phasellus sed
        sollicitudin sem, eget porta urna. Phasellus lacus diam, imperdiet non dapibus porttitor, gravida vitae odio. Pellentesque sit amet risus at risus molestie rutrum sed sit amet mauris. Donec at tortor vulputate, tempus dolor id, rutrum nulla. Vivamus
        cursus orci vel purus ornare blandit.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SCSS mixin. It's for align left the last row items with justify-content: space-between, but I think It could help you.

```
@mixin last-row-flexbox($num-columns, $width-items){

  $filled-space: $width-items * $num-columns;
  $margin: calc((100% - #{$filled-space}) / (#{$num-columns} - 1));

  $num-cols-1 : $num-columns - 1;

  &:nth-child(#{$num-columns}n+1):nth-last-child(-n+#{$num-cols-1}) ~ & {
    margin-left: $margin;
  }
  @for $i from 1 through $num-columns - 2 { 
    $index: $num-columns - $i;
    &:nth-child(#{$num-columns}n+#{$index}):last-child{
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the codepen link: http://codepen.io/diana_aceves/pen/KVGNZg

You just have to set the items width in percentage and number of columns.

I hope this can help you.